# Synchronising Facebook events with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, facebook-events

Is there any way to keep the two synchronised? So when a new event is added to facebook (regardless of attending or not), it comes up on google calendar?

I've tried pasting the webcal link from Facebook into google calendar, but this only gives me one event (the one furthest in the future).

Answer (score 5):

I just did it and was given more than the next event:

1. Go to https://www.facebook.com/events/list
2. Click the **Gear** on the right side of the screen
   [image: Facebook Events Gear Menu displayed]
3. In the drop-down menu, click on **Export**
4. In the modal that is displayed, right-click on the **upcoming events** link and select **Copy Link Address**
   [image: Facebook Export events and birthdays modal]
5. Paste the link into Google Calendar subscribe

Comment: Stupid javascript/mac screenshot capture wouldn't let me capture the moused over export link... sad day when I can't give you the example of the highlighted menu option. </rant>

Comment: Facebook has done a site change and the export option seems to be gone. Has anyone found a way to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has changed the layout of the events pages (around Oct 2014). From what I can tell you can't get to the URL from the overall events pages anymore, instead you have to go to an individual event then:

First get the link from Facebook

- Go to an individual event
- Click on "..."
- Click on "Export Event"
- Copy the webcal link listed under "Subscribe to all upcoming events on your calendar". It will look like webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=999319999&key=AXXXXXXXX0XXXFe.

Then put the link in Google

- Click on down arrow next to "Other calendars"
- Click on "Add by URL"
- Paste the webcal link into the URL box
- Click on Add Calendar