# Is there a way to synchronise 'attending' Facebook events with Google Calendar?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar, synchronization

There is a way to sync all Facebook events with Google Calendar: [Synchronising Facebook events with Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/synchronising-facebook-events-with-google-calendar) but I couldn't find a way to sync only attending events.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a web service at the following URL
http://eventcal.flown.io/
that lets you filter your calendar sync by "attending (going)", "maybe/interested" and or "unanswered"

*Screenshot of EventCal Web Service Website*:
[image: Screenshot of EventCal Web Service]

The code for it is also available on GitHub at https://github.com/simonbengtsson/eventcal

Comment: Sadly I can't find a way to export the facebook url anymore, On Facebook events I'm only given an .ics file to download. So I can't get http://eventcal.flown.io/ to work for me anymore. :(

Comment: why not contact the dev and ask if he can fix it, or if you are a dev yourself, its on github, so you may be able to fix it yourself